# Glossy white Background for my website

Tags: css

I am trying to set my website's background color to a glossy white background, the same look and feel of Linkedin's or most new generation website's background color. I tried to set `background-color: #fff;` in my CSS file but the background color still looks very dull white.

Is there any way that I can make the background color smooth and glossy white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linkedIn, containers have `background-color:#fff`. How to make them glossy? Try to put some other, dark color to background of body, and then white containers will be "more white". For example, set `background-color` of `body` to `#E2E2E2` or any other dark color. Or use some background image, like LinkedIn.

Comment: I was setting the body background to #fff. Could you please let me know what you meant by container ? Thanks !

Comment: By container i meant other 'div' elements inside of 'body'. Background-color of body should be some dark color, and background-color of other elements inside of body should be white. Just look at LinkedIn.

Answer (score 2):

Go here: http://www.colorpicker.com/ and choose the colour you want.

Replace your `background-color` with that.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of your `background color` ,replace the color and try,it will work